# How to link to an object with main in it?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, clang, ld

I'd like to link an object file (`.o` file) with a `main()` to another object file that also has a `main()`.

I'd like to ignore the `main()` in the second file, but use the `main()` in the second `.o` file. Is there a way to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNU linker has an option `--allow-multiple-definition`.  When that is used, `ld` ignores any duplicate definitions, using only the first one it encounters for each symbol.  This applies to definitions of *all* symbols, of course, not just `main`.  To use that through the `gcc` driver, you would use `gcc`'s `-Wl,` option:

```
gcc -o myprog -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition main.o second.o
```

Comment: Thanks. It should be definition not definitions.

Comment: Yes, @user1424739, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the two object files are `a.o` and `b.o`. Both the files have `main()` but you only want to use the `main()` from `a.o`.

Firstly you have to find the exact name of the function (this is necessary in case there is name mangling or `_` prepended).

Run -

```
objdump -t | grep "main"
```

This will show the symbol that has the word `main` in it. Pick the appropriate function name.
Now we will rename it to something else -

```
objcopy --redefine-sym main=some_rubbish_name_not_anywhere b.o
```

(replace main with whatever symbol name you got in the above command)

Now you can link your object files as you normally would -

```
clang a.o b.o -o program
```

The other way would be to completely strip off the `main` symbol from `b.o` (as suggested by @ChrisBodd in comments) -

```
objcopy --strip-symbol=main b.o
```

Comment: Is there a way to delete an function from a `.o` file?

Comment: You can use `--strip-symbol=main` to simply remove the main symbol rather than renaming it.  That won't reomve the *function*, just the symbol referring to it.  `-N main` is the same (short option instead of long)

Comment: @user1424739 there is no way to "remove" an entire function. Because sometimes the linker doesn't even know where a function actually ends. But as ChrisDodd suggested, you can strip just the symbol name and it won't interfere with your linking.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I agree, stripping also works. The only difference is that the references (if any) to `main` from `b.o` will still link to the version in `b.o` if you rename and will point to the one in `a.o` if you strip. I think it depends on OP's use case. But I think they mean what you have suggested.